# How to handle error on concatenation two string in Assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, masm32, irvine32

For my assignment, I want to concatenate two string. This is my code so far. the result should be **helloworld** , but it only displays **hello** :-(

How should I add *source* string at the **end** of *destination* ?

What I'm missing ?

```
;--------------------In main.CPP

    extern "C" void __stdcall StrCatAsm(char[], char[]);

    ;main
              char str1[] = {'h','e','l','l','o',0};
              char str2[] = {'w','o','r','l','d',0};
              StrCatAsm(str1,str2)
              string1 = 'h','e','l','l','o','w','o','r','l','d',0
    ;------------------In main.asm

    Concat PROC  uses eax edi ecx esi,
                        destination:DWORD,
                        source:DWORD

        mov al,0             ;looking for zero terminated
        mov ecx,100          ;number of possible loop
        mov edi, source    
        repne scasb           ;look for end of source
        not ecx               ;ecx is 6
        mov esi, destination  
        rep movsb            ;loop for copy ESI into EDI

        ret
    Concat ENDP
```

Comment: Probably unrelated but: Are you sure there is enough space after `'hello'` to concatenate anything at all? Or were you supposed to *copy* `'hello'` into (unused) `destination` and then paste `'world'` after it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How should I add source string at the end of destination ?

If this is what you need then you should look for the terminating zero in the **destination** (and not in the source as your code does!).
Once the terminating zero is found, your `EDI` register will be past its location and thus you need to back up 1 position!

```
mov  al, 0             ;looking for zero terminated
mov  ecx, 100          ;any large number will do!
mov  edi, DESTINATION
repne scasb            ;look for end of DESTINATION
DEC  EDI
mov  ecx, 6            ;length of SOURCE {'w','o','r','l','d',0};
mov  esi, SOURCE  
rep movsb              ;loop for copy ESI into EDI
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the pseudo code for string concatenation:

```
t1 = get string length of str1         ; find length not including zero terminate
t2 = get string length of str2         ; find length not including zero terminate
ct = (t1 + t2) + 1                     ; total length + 1 for zero terminate
dest = allocate memory for size ct     ; get total string length

n = 0
nt = 0

while str1[n] != 0                      ; Until you hit str1 zero terminate
   dest[nt] = str1[n]
   n = n + 1
   nt = nt+1

n = 0

while str2[n] != 0                      ; Until you hit str1 zero terminate
   dest[nt] = str2[n]
   n = n + 1
   nt = nt + 1

dest[nt] = 0                            ; final terminate string
```